# Toastr notification not working on asp.net web forms

Tags: asp.net, toastr

I'm trying to use toastr notifications in my ASP.NET web forms app. I have written the following code:

Toastr.cs

```
public static class Toastr
    {
        public  static void ShowToastr(this System.Web.UI.Page page, string message, string title, string type)
        {
            page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "toastr_message", String.Format("toastr.{0}('{1}','{2}', { positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width', timeOut: 5e3, closeButton: !0, debug: !1, newestOnTop: !0, progressBar: !0, preventDuplicates: !0, onclick: null, showDuration: '300', hideDuration: '1000', extendedTimeOut:'1000', showEasing: 'swing', hideEasing: 'linear', showMethod: 'fadeIn', hideMethod: 'fadeOut', tapToDismiss: !1 });", type.ToLower(), message, title), addScriptTags: true);
        }
    }
```

and then on button click I'm doing this:

```
//code for insertion
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "toastr_message", "toastr.success('Successfully added URD','Success!')", true);
```

and on runtime I am getting error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: toastr is not defined
>     at test.aspx:407

Answer (score 1):

Has the toastr library been declared properly in the page?

Is jQuery declared too?

To test if everything is set up on the page: Open the console and type in

```
toastr.info("title")
```

That should display a simple notification. If that doesn't work then you'll start getting error messages to help you resolve